# Asking rspec to stub find(1), instead it's encountering find(1, {:conditions=>nil})

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I'm telling rspec:

```
@foo1 = Factory(:foo)
@foo2 = Factory(:foo)
Foo.stub(:find).with(@foo1.id){@foo1}
Foo.stub(:find).with(@foo2.id){@foo2}
```

As a spec for this code:

```
f = Foo.find(foo_id)
```

And I get this error:

```
expected: (1)
got: (1, {:conditions=>nil})
```

I thought perhaps stub can't be told what parameters to expect, and I have to just use `should_receive`, even though that's not the behavior I'm testing in this spec -- but I tried that and it has the same error.

Comment: Where's your expectation (the line with the .should)?

Comment: no expectation, only the stub -- I changed the title to reflect this now.

Comment: F.stub!(:find).with(@f.id).and_return(@f) ??

Comment: Can you show us the full example? It's not clear what your expectation is.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas/input -- I realized my problem is from elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing something. The stub just returns a canned response so you don't actually have to retrieve data from the database. You still need an expectation on your own code.

```
#In some spec...
@foo = mock(Foo)
Foo.stub!(:find).and_return(@foo)
#...do stuff that calls Foo.find...
x.should be_y
```

Of course, you can always use fixtures to seed your test database, then you don't have to mock ActiveRecord at all...

Comment: You made me realize something I didn't mention about my spec, which is that I want to stub two different invocations of `find` -- maybe rspec can't do this, and I should just use `should_receive` instead (even though that isn't the behavior I'm actually testing, which is why I wnated to use `stub` instead)

Comment: Actually I tried `should_receive` and got the same error -- my question has been fleshed out a bit more. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas/input -- I realized my problem is from elsewhere in my code.

Comment: Though strictly, the use of fixtures (or factories, or anything that actually makes use of a DB) makes it an integration test not a unit test.